# How to handle the delay that occurs between an append() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, arrays

I am appending an array to a div using jquery, I want to show a small loading indicator while this happens, so I threw a call back function onto my append logic. This works, however, my loader will fire off it's `.hide()` before my array is painted into the div.

Is there a way I can only run the `.hide()` after the array has finished painting?

```
var contentpush = [];
// create x-amount of divs (x being 'tabs')
for (var i = 0; i < tabs; i++){
    contentpush.push('<li class="tab" role="tab"><a href="#tab'+(i+1)+'"><span class="icon"><span class="'+contentformat[i].icon+'" ></span></span><span class="title">'+contentformat[i].title+'</span></a></li>');
}

$('.tablist').append(contentpush.join('')).ready(function(){$('#skeleton').hide(); });;
```

Here is a gif of what is going on as well:
[image: Slow Arrays]

As you can see, the skeletal frame loader will disappear long before my array is actually painted into the div. Any thoughts on this are greatly appreciated!

Comment: can you put code in fiddle or codepen?

Comment: Not exactly, the whole web app is built on a companies cms, so it's using those cms modules to handle some of my logic, but the code included is the only part that handles the append function

Comment: have you tried the load event instead of the ready one from jquery?

Comment: @ether I doubt the effects on append still you can use .show('slow') to slow down the fast changing element.

Comment: @mnemosdev just tried using .load, and it doesn't even show the skeletal frames with that. I think I definitely need the .ready because then it's looking for after the append starts, rather than when the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting a timeout for some milliseconds?

Comment: The load times vary by browser/computer, I don't want to set a static time for it to run, just in case its a faster or shorter load time somewhere else. But if I can't find an answer that handles it automatically, this may be my solution. :/

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the jQuery `.append()` function does not include a callback. There is no way to really check for completion of it, as it supposedly happens immediately. synchronously in the order they come, unless you explicitly tell them to be asynchronous by using a timeout or interval. [see this](http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/03/43439-reasons-to-use-append-correctly)

This means that your `.append` method will be executed and nothing else will execute until that method have finished its job. try following

```
// set a time interval for the event to complete.
$(contentpush).hide().appendTo(".tablist").fadeIn(1000);

 // a small tweak to set a call back function.
$(".tablist").append(contentpush).append(function() { $('#skeleton').hide(); });
```

Comment: So what I noticed is that on load, the ul will be populated, it's just the render time that is killing me. If I check for the `tabs` element before removing the `skeleton` div, it will do it on load/immediately. But it seems that there is no way to tell once the lis are actually painted/rendered on the page.